# Avoid including untested functions in coverage report

Tags: go

Is there a way to force cover tool to not include indirectly called functions into account when creating a coverage report percentage?

For example `pkg/response/response.go:Success|Write` are not tested at all but because `src/api/info/info.go` is fully tested and calling `Success|Write` functions, they get added to coverage as if they were also tested! Same goes with `storage` functions.

```
$ go test -v -race -timeout=180s -count=1 -covermode=atomic -coverpkg=./... -coverprofile cover.out ./...
$ go tool cover -func cover.out
```

```
cmd/app/main.go:22: main            0.0%

pkg/response/response.go:28:  Success       66.7% <- not tested at all but `src/api/info/info.go` is tested and calling this function
pkg/response/response.go:138: Write         57.1% <- not tested at all but `src/api/info/info.go` is tested and calling this function

src/api/info/handler.go:7: NewHandler       0.0%
src/api/info/info.go:15:   Handle           100.0% <- tested

src/api/v1/users/handler.go:22:       NewHandler        0.0%
src/api/v1/users/posts/handler.go:17: NewHandler        0.0%

src/storage/database/error.go:10:    isNotFoundError. 100.0% <- not tested at all but `src/storage/database/storage.go` is tested and calling this function
src/storage/database/error.go:14:    isConflictError  75.0% <- not tested at all but `src/storage/database/storage.go` is tested and calling this function
src/storage/database/storage.go:25:  CreateUser       80.0% <- tested
src/storage/database/storage.go:56:  FindUser         83.3% <- tested
src/storage/database/storage.go:87:  DeleteUser       80.0% <- tested
src/storage/database/storage.go:115: CreatePost       84.6% <- tested
src/storage/database/storage.go:155: ListPostsForUser 70.0% <- tested

total:                              (statements)        26.7%
```

Comment: If the function Success is called, it's tested. There is no such notion of "called directly". What would that mean anyway? Like "must be directly invoked by the `func TestXYZ(t *testing.T)`? That makes no sense.

Comment: "called directly" - I meant there is no `func Test_Response_Success(t *testing.T)` in `reponse_test.go` so hence I wanted to explicitly ignore such cases in the coverage report. I am aware that `func Test_Info_Handle(t *testing.T)` in `info_test.go` is calling this `Success` and produce coverage report for it.

Answer (score 0):

> s there a way to force cover tool to not include indirectly called functions into account when creating a coverage report percentage?

No.

(Simply because this is basically undoable and not useful in general.)